# Simple Update query not working because of syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

Hi i cant figure out this.. i even try direct in phpmyadmin

this query is not working

```
UPDATE orsil_quote SET status=4 WHERE order=199
```

Direct on Php Myadmin i get MySQL said: #1064 (syntax error around order=199)

I have tried

```
 UPDATE orsil_quote SET status=`4` WHERE order=`199`
 UPDATE `orsil_quote` SET status=4 WHERE order=199
 UPDATE `orsil_quote` SET status=`4` WHERE order=`199`

 UPDATE orsil_quote SET status='4' WHERE order='199'
 UPDATE 'orsil_quote' SET status=4 WHERE order=199
 UPDATE 'orsil_quote' SET status='4' WHERE order='199'

 UPDATE orsil_quote SET status="4" WHERE order="199"
 UPDATE "orsil_quote" SET status=4 WHERE order=199
 UPDATE "orsil_quote" SET status="4" WHERE order="199"
```

I can confirm the column orsil_quote does exists, also column status and column order, all of them exists and the name has been checked hundred times.

What is happening!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` is a [reserved MySQL keyword.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) If you are going to use it as a column identifier you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
UPDATE `orsil_quote` SET `status`=4 WHERE `order`=199
```

Although it would be better to alter your table and not use a reserved keyword as a column identifier.